# Logging problems with tomcat in a docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy a web app using a docker container, which i managed to do, the problem is with the configuration of the tomcat server within the container which behaves a bit differently from running the tomcat server directly on my os. I can’t manage to find the the catalina.out file anywhere even if the `catalina.sh` explicitly creates it:

```
if [ -z “$CATALINA_OUT” ] ; then
CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi
```

I altered the path to use a known path but to no avail. Note that adding logging.properties helps create the catalina log but when set to rotatable dates all log files created, i need to a standard catalina.out file which I run scripts on to analyse my web app.

Please note that I am relatively new to working with containers and tomcat.
Thank you for you help!

I have tried multiple approaches when creating my docker containers i used the following configurations Dockerfiles to test :

First approach

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/java/tomcat:11u13-zulu-ubuntu-tomcat-9.0.54
COPY conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
COPY conf/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
COPY webapps/webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY conf/logging.properties /usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

My web app starts but no `catalina.out` in the path specified in `catalina.sh`.

Second approach

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME


ENV TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR $CATALINA_HOME/native-jni-lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}$TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR

ENV GPG_KEYS 48F8E69F6390C9F25CFEDCD268248959359E722B A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243

ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 9
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 9.0.75
ENV TOMCAT_SHA512 e29905e693598b64d958dd22b8d866590163917bdc6e1cfd363a8a06f97ecc89284b863b3ab2448f43903623564c3fd952c7a9bd33df8476d57f6873c2d463c7

COPY --from=tomcat:9.0.75-jdk11-temurin-focal $CATALINA_HOME $CATALINA_HOME
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    xargs -rt apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends < "$TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR/.dependencies.txt"; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN set -eux; \
    nativeLines="$(catalina.sh configtest 2>&1)"; \
    nativeLines="$(echo "$nativeLines" | grep 'Apache Tomcat Native')"; \
    nativeLines="$(echo "$nativeLines" | sort -u)"; \
    if ! echo "$nativeLines" | grep -E 'INFO: Loaded( APR based)? Apache Tomcat Native library' >&2; then \
        echo >&2 "$nativeLines"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi

COPY conf/server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
COPY conf/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
COPY webapps/webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY conf/logging.properties /usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```